# Bing Map not bringing city in India

Tags: bing-api, bing-maps

Does Bing Maps Api show all cities inside India ?
I am currently using the Bing Maps APi inside my application to find coordinates and City based on Postal Code entered by the user. This is how i am using the api.

```
http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?CountryRegion=INDIA&postalCode=683101&key=BingMapKey
```

This returns the latitude and longitude, but locality (City) is blank.

How can i get the city too ?

I was planning to use google geocoder before, but google prohibits using their api without showing the map.

Thanks !

Comment: They prohibit using their API without a map?

Comment: Yes its in their rules page :(

Comment: Not sure if its okay to use their api just as a lookup ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that Bing Maps currently does not support postal codes in India. As such the returned result is for the country of India.